# Create div for every X divs

Tags: php, wordpress

I have function right now:

```
<?php while ( have_rows('proyects') ) : the_row(); ?>

        <div class="box">
            <p><?php the_sub_field("texte");?></p>
        </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Which outputs something like this:

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

The problem is that I want it to output every three `box` a div container so the final result should look like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: if((have_rows % 3) == 0) place div?

Comment: I don't know, that's why i'm asking here :)

Comment: Not directly related, but there is a lot you can do with css so you might not even need this.

Comment: @codek: What I posted should work quite fine. But as jeroen said, you could probably get away doing this with CSS.

Comment: How can I do it with css @jeroen?

Comment: Not this directly, but perhaps solve the problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: That is some weird code... Isn't there a function to return `all_the_rows()` ? If so, you can use `array_chunk($rows, 3)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php 
        $counter = 0;
        while ( have_rows('proyects') ) : the_row(); 

        if($counter%3 == 0 && $counter != 0)
        echo '</div>';
        if($counter%3 == 0)
        echo '<div class="container">';
        $counter++;
?>
        <div class="box">
            <p><?php the_sub_field("texte");?></p>
        </div>



<?php endwhile; 
   if ($counter != 0)
   echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: You're missing some `<?` and `?>`, but yeah, that would do it.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, it creates one container for every div

Comment: for every div? hmmmm... lemme see.

Comment: @codek, the edited version, is it giving you the same result of one container per div?

Comment: No, but now it gives me every `container` inside another `container` and so on...

Comment: @hmm, I just tested it out with 9 dummy posts and I get three containers each containing 3 divs with class="box" each containing one paragraph. I will keep checking though.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it looks like this would omit the final `</div>`.

Comment: @Mike, Good catch! Let me modify it to add the final div.

Comment: @Mike, Think it's complete now.

Comment: @Charles OK, now a new problem is if there are no rows, you'll always be echoing an extra `</div>`. You should instead work this into the `while` loop.

Comment: @Mike, I just checked it with the counter. So if there are no posts the counter will never go beyond 0.